# Menu "Logout" in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a menu with several items, when I click on `Logout`, I don't return on the page `login` but on the page `home`.

*app.componentt.ts*

```
export class AppComponent {
    currentUser: User = new User();

    public configuration: DashboardLayoutConfiguration;
    public links: NavigationLink[] = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthService
    ) {
        this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(
            (x) => (this.currentUser = x)
        );

        this.configuration = new DashboardLayoutConfiguration(
            SidePanelPosition.LEFT,
            SidePanelState.OPEN
        );
        this.createLinks();
    }

    private createLinks() {
        this.links = [
            new NavigationLink(
                'Sélection du portefeuille',
                ['portfolio'],
                'fa fa-credit-card'
            ),
            new NavigationLink(
                'Corporate actions',
                ['corporate-action'],
                'fa fa-university'
            ),
            new NavigationLink('Valeurs', ['value'], 'fa fa-bar-chart'),
            new NavigationLink('Indices Boursiers', ['indice'], 'fa fa-line-chart'),
            new NavigationLink('Devises', ['devise'], 'fa fa-money'),
            new NavigationLink(
                'Tableau de valeurs',
                ['valuable-table'],
                'fa fa-list-alt'
            ),
            new NavigationLink('Logout', ['/login'], 'fa fa-circle-o-notch'),
        ];
    }

    logout() {
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
 <app-dashboard-layout
[configuration]="configuration"
*ngIf="currentUser; else notLoggedIn">

<div container="sidePanel">
   <app-navigation-side-panel [links]="links"></app-navigation-side-panel>
</div>
<div container="navigationBar" *ngIf="currentUser">
   <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
</div>
<div container="mainContent">
   <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
</app-dashboard-layout>
<ng-template #notLoggedIn>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

I don't understand where is my problem, please? I share you my code -> [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7twhut?file=src/app/shared/_models/user.ts).

The password is `test1` (for information).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login component you have:

```
// redirect to home if already logged in
if (this.authenticationService.currentUserVal) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

That says, if you are already logged in, navigate to '/' and in your case its "PortfolioComponent" component

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the line `this.router.navigate(['/PortfolioComponent']);`, but why when I logout. My menu appears always, please? [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7twhut?file=src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts)

Comment: You did not understand me. I said that in your router its says for the route ''/' it will go to  "PortfolioComponent" component. Basically on logout action you should call this.authenticationService.logout() and then redirect to login page.